# Get polygons inside a polygon

Tags: arcmap, visual-studio, arcobjects

I have developed a tool in arcobjects on Visual studio 2010,
the tool works fine but once installed my ArcMap drawing the map (refreshing) and printing slows down..

I have used `ITopologicalOperator` in the program.

Should I release any `com objects` here if yes what object should I release

Please guide.

Comment: Please add more detail about your code.  If possible, include part of your code in your question.  It is difficult for people to recommend what to change, if they don't know what you have.

Comment: More detail required.. are you responding to an event? (mousemove, viewrefreshed...) most of the time you don't need to worry about releasing the object references but there are a few special circumstances (like insert cursor) where you either release the com object or close the application or a locking situation occurs.